# Need help setting up Potrace for use in C++

Tags: c++, c, module, libraries, potrace

I want to make a program that uses Potrace to convert bitmap images to SVG images but first I need to figure out how to install it properly. Currently, I got the precompiled version but the folder only contains .exe files READMEs without that much information that I can get from them and .1 files which I have no idea what they are. Do I have the wrong library downloaded or what I can't figure a single thing out? I am not sure whether or not I will be able to get this thing up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have checked this
https://github.com/skyrpex/potrace

compile and install the code. Configuring with option --with-libpotrace  will install the desired libraries.